# не нажимается inline кнопка telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

from text_ln import messages

from function import functions

from kb import kb

import sqlite3

bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    functions.first(user_id=message.chat.id)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'choose language', reply_markup=kb.start)



@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'ru' or 'en')
def language(call):
    if call.data == "ru":
            language1 = 'ru'
            db = sqlite3.connect('language.db')
            cursor = db.cursor()
            q = cursor.execute(f"UPDATE user SET language = ? WHERE user_id = ?",(language1,call.message.chat.id))
            db.commit()
            db.close()
            start_2(call)
            bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id)
    elif call.data == "en":
            language1 = 'en'
            db = sqlite3.connect('language.db')
            cursor = db.cursor()
            q = cursor.execute(f"UPDATE user SET language = ? WHERE user_id = ?",(language1,call.message.chat.id))
            db.commit()
            db.close()
            start_2(call)
            bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id)

def start_2(call):
    language = functions.ln(user_id=call.message.chat.id)
    name = bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, messages.name[f'name_{language}'])
    bot.register_next_step_handler(name, start_3)

def start_3(call):
    language = functions.ln(user_id=call.from_user.id)
    functions.name(user_id=call.from_user.id,name=call.text)

    name_1 = {'name_1_ru':f'Вас зовут верно {call.text}?', 'name_1_en':f'Your name is {call.text} rigth ?'}

    name = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = messages.name_2_r[f'name_2_{language}'], callback_data = 'right')
    item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = messages.name_2_w[f'name_2_{language}'], callback_data = 'wrong')
    name.add(item1,item2)

    bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, name_1[f'name_1_{language}'],reply_markup=name)  

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'right' or 'wrong')
def name(call):
    if call.data == 'right':
        video = open("/home/roman/Desktop/urist/photo/Видео 1.mp4", "rb")
        bot.send_video(call.message.chat.id,video, caption=f"""
    Добрый день, {functions.select_name(user_id=call.from_user.id)} 
            """)
    elif call.data == 'wrong':
        start_2(call)


bot.polling()
```

После нажатия на кнопки ru или en все срабатывает, дальше кнопки right или wrong не срабатывают, если все помещаю в один хендлер, работает, если пишу в таком формате, 2 хендлер отваливается

Answer (score 0):

Я бы рекомендовал сделать так:

- Создаем кнопки, callback делаем с префиксом (lang_ru/lang_en, vote_right/vote_wrong)
- Создаем хендлеры, в них прописываем фильтр - pattern='^{префикс}'
- Получаем данные (убираем префикс у callback)

Как это выглядит в коде:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(pattern='^lang')
def language(call):
    language=call.data.split('_')[1] #получаем ru/en
    db = sqlite3.connect('language.db')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(
        "UPDATE user SET language = ? WHERE user_id = ?",
        (language, call.message.chat.id))
    db.commit()
    db.close()
    start_2(call)
    bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id)
```

Совет: бд и курсор определяем в начале кода, чтобы не подключаться каждый раз. Так нам останется только делать .commit() каждый раз, а не подключаться-отключаться и т.д.

Comment: разве в телеботе есть фильтр `text_startswith`?

Comment: Извиняюсь, затупил, ответ по факту под aiogram... Переписал ответ, взгляните)

Answer (score 0):

Вы неправильно прописали условие. Делайте так

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data in ('ru', 'en'))
```